# Quadratic sequence: sum of the elements between given two elements

Tags: sequences-and-series, quadratics

I've googled a lot but couldn't find any solution for my problem. Is there any formula for calculating the sum of the elements between given two elements of quadratic sequence?
For example: I have a sequence 2, 7, 14, 23, 34, 47 ...

I want to calculate the sum of the elements between, let's say, 4th and 6th elements.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on whether you mean to include those, that would be $S_6 - S_3$ (if both are included) or $S_6 - S_4$ (if only the ending one is included), etc. A formula for the $S_n$ of a quadratic sequence can be found easily (if searching doesn't find one for a general quadratic sequence, it will certainly find one for the basic $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$ and you can use that to derive a more general one)

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks)